# Accessing a HTTPS website using a Flex/AIR HTML component?

Tags: html, apache-flex, https, air, payment

Is it possible to access remote pages through https when using the HTML component inside a Flex AIR application?

I'm looking to build a credit card payment integration into an AIR application and the easy way would be to send the user to a payment service within a browser embedded into the application.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, according to the doc, you can:
http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/html/help.html?content=ProgrammingHTMLAndJavaScript_05.html

Try with any https website:

```
<mx:HTML id="content">
    <mx:location><![CDATA[https://www.fldemo.nsf.gov/]></mx:location>
</mx:HTML>
```